# Collapse/Open a table with font-awesome icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently my label is collapsible, and it collapses a table. I want to add font-awesome icons with the label or heading; caret-down for table open and caret-right for table closed or collapsed. This should happen on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've created a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/gjk3zepd/2/
>
> This could solve your problem

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.collapse').hide();
  $('.content').hide();
  $('.expand, .collapse').bind('click',function(){
    $('.collapse').toggle();
    $('.expand').toggle();
    $('.content').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="expand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>

<a href="#" class="collapse"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>

<div class="content">
Div Content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to achieve toggle using a single icon. This code might be useful.

```js
$("a").click(function(){
  if($("div.content").is(':hidden')){
    $("div.content").show();
    $(this).addClass('toggle');
  }else{
    $(this).removeClass('toggle');
}    
});
```

```css
a i.fa-angle-down{display:none;}
a i.fa-angle-up{display:block;}
a.toggle i.fa-angle-down{display:block;}
a.toggle i.fa-angle-up{display:none;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Toggle</title>
  
</head>
  <body>
    <a class="toggle">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```